# How to bind custom dependecy property to control's view model?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I need to create a control with few inputs / output with lots of internal functionality. I think the best approach is to create `Dependency Properties` for interaction with other application parts and have a `private` `view model` with hidden functions.

Here is my sample:

Window

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:app="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
<StackPanel>
    <DatePicker x:Name="DatePicker" />
    <app:MyControl DateCtrl="{Binding ElementName=DatePicker, Path=SelectedDate}" />
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MyControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.MyControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:app="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <app:ViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateVM}" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Control code-behind

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
public partial class MyControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static DependencyProperty DateCtrlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DateCtrl", typeof(DateTime), typeof(MyControl));
    public DateTime DateCtrl
    {
        get { return (DateTime) GetValue(DateCtrlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DateCtrlProperty, value); }
    }
}
}
```

ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private DateTime _dateVM;
        public DateTime DateVM
        {
            get { return _dateVM; }
            set
            {
                _dateVM = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DateVM");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I need to achieve is to propagate `date` chosen in `DatePicker` down to `MyControl's` `view model`. Alternatively, is there any better pattern to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is a common misconception that all views should have a view model. However, it is usually far simpler (and more appropriate) for `UserControl`s that are used as controls to simply use their own `DependencyProperty`s.

The problem with your method is that you have assigned the `UserControl DataContext` internally, so it cannot be set from outside the control. The solution is to *not* set the `DataContext` internally, but instead to use a `RelativeSource Binding` to access the `UserControl DependencyProperty`s like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DateCtrl, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type YourLocalPrefix:MyControl}}}" />
```

If you really have to use an internal view model, then declare a `DependencyProperty` of that type and data bind to it in the same way that I showed above:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding YourViewModelProperty.DateVM, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type YourLocalPrefix:MyControl}}}" />
```

Comment: This will work and I will probably do it so, but I am afraid that it will end up with huge amount of code on `Control` itself like with my old `WinForms` app. Other disadvantage is I won't be able to test the presentation logic separately.

Comment: Then use the second example and provide the view model as a `DependencyProperty`. Alternatively, just data bind from this `UserControl` directly to the view model of a parent `UserControl` or `Window`.

Answer (score 0):

The DatePicker should have it's own DatePickerViewModel which defines a SelectedDate property or dependency property.  You should define the XAML of the DatePicker control to use this dedicated ViewModel.

Then, when you use the *control*, you can set the binding like so:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=DateVM, 
            Mode=TwoWay, 
            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Note that DateVM is not a property of the date picker, but a property on the consuming view model (or in this case, Main Window).  When the picker is opened, it will default to the date already set in DateVM.

The other thing is that your picker doesn't allow any picking at the moment - it's just a text block!

Comment: `DatePicker` in the sample represents the outside world which is aware only of `DateCtrl` property and doesn't know that there is some internal view model which has `DateVM`. The `TextBlock` is used only to visualize the internal property `DateVM` which is in current sample unset.